# Order of $B$ modulo $p^h$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $B$ and $p$ relatively primes and $e=\operatorname{ord}_p(B)$. How can I show that for $h\geqslant 0$, $\operatorname{ord}_{p^h}(B)=ep^g$, where $g=g(h)$?

I've been trying using the fact that $e\mid p-1$ and the formula for the Euler function for $p^h$, $\phi(p^h)$ but I can't arrive to the conclusion.

Comment: Write $B^e$ as $kp+1$. Now try to prove that $(kp+1)^{p^g} -1$ is divisible by $p^h$ for some $g \in \mathbb{N}$. You can do this by observing that $(kp+1)^{p^n}-1$ is actually divisible by $p^{n+1}$. Try proving this by induction.

Comment: @JefLaga Your hint is useful but after doing that, how can I prove that this value is actually the order?

Comment: Note that the order divides $e.p^{h-1}$, try to prove that $e$ divides the order. Then you're finished.